# Using a regulator or not?

Tags: power-supply, voltage-regulator, battery-charging

We have designed a board for mass production . This board has a few components on it, that works with 3v3 , such as MCU, Wi-Fi, and a few more sensors.

We used to have a battery, 3.7v to power the board directly, and later on, we have decided that we must use a regulator, because its more safe .
the regulator is `AMS1117`

After some research, we found out that this regulator(and others) must have 1V more in its input,relative to its output .

So, using a battery pack of `3.7v lithium`, will not work properly for such regulators(3.3v) , even when its charged with `4.2v` .

We found out that logically ,connecting the battery **directly** (no regulator) to the board is much clever, because you can "enjoy" the battery power as long as it is `> 3.3v`  .

Our only concern is that we are not using a regulator, and its not healthy .

Is that a good thing to do- "professional" ?

do you think of more options,such a zener diode instead of a regulator ?

Comment: Check the datasheets of your components, and when everything is able to run at the highest possible voltage then you can do it.

Comment: Look up SEPIC voltage converters. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-ended_primary-inductor_converter

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "Healthy"? and how does "professionalism" translate to design?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're asking questions like this, you're *not* ready for "mass production", whether you wish to be professional or not.

You need to look at the supply voltage *range* of everything, and then see if the *range* of your battery's voltage from full to flat will work.  If not, then you will likely need either a very-low-dropout linear regulator (hint: the AMS1117 isn't), or a type of buck-boost switch-mode regulator that can provide a stable 3.3V supply from a source that can be either above or below the output (i.e. as the battery goes from full to flat).  For a linear regulator option, even if the battery voltage drops below the regulator's drop-out voltage (for a 3.3v LDO regulator's output, lets say it's 3.5V, 200mV above output), then you might be able to get away with that - the regulator won't really be in regulation, but depending on your load profile that may or may not matter much.

When you say a "3.7 lithium" battery, its range between full to flat will be ~4.2V full, to no less than 3.0V flat.  And you *don't* charge lithium with a constant voltage source.  Well, at least not at first - lithium battery charging is at least a 2-stage process, first constant-current, then constant-voltage, using a charge management chip specific to Lithium chemistry.

You are not ready for mass production, not even close.

Comment: My question was not if i am ready or not for mass production, you have no idea what is our product, and who is involved ( you even might know them) . Your answer does not provide any new information to me, you assume that i didn't think about the range of my parts, and its not true.  just because the range is ok, i did asked this question . another thing, dont be so angry with yourself . its not good for you .

Comment: The tone may be a bit harsh, but the point is sound. If you need to ask a technical question like this, you aren't ready for mass production, or any type of production. You are making a prototype. That being said, you can certainly find LDO regulators that can run much closer to 3.3V than the one you've chosen.

Answer (score 2):

If I were you I would use a regulator, and it is not too hard to find one that suits your requirements.
As you have little difference between the V<sub>in</sub> and V<sub>out</sub>, you can go with an Low-Drop Out regulator, such as [this](http://www.ti.com/product/TPS736/datasheet).

I found this in less than 10 minutes. It has an excellent [WEBENCH](http://webench.ti.com/webench5/power/webench5.cgi?VinMin=3.5&VinMax=4&O1V=3.3&O1I=0.4&base_pn=TPS73633&AppType=None&op_TA=30&lang_chosen=en_US&optfactor=3) to help you make your design.

Here is the recommended schematic:

[image]

As you can see it can take 3.5V - 4V input voltage while providing the stable 3.3V.
I do not know how much current does your application need, this one can supply up to 400mA.

Answer (score 2):

Just off the top of my head, you may use some off-the-shelf DC-DC converter module like [this one](https://www.pololu.com/product/2122): 3.3V fixed output, 2.7-11.8V input range with nice efficiency especially with load currents <500mA.

[image]